# Asynchronous call handling while reading a file

Tags: node.js

```
var rd = fs.createReadStream(source);
console.log('success');
```

In the above code, since, node js being asynchronous, May the the console.log('success') be executed before the file is read.
how to prevent it in this case.

Comment: `createReadStream` is not an asynchronous function.

Answer (score 3):

As @Quentin mentioned, `createReadStream` is not asynchronous. But either way, if you want to verify that the stream is readable, you could do the following:

```
var rd = fs.createReadStream(source);
rd.on('readable', function() {
  // there is some data to read now
  console.log('success');
})
```